# World-space depth from directional shadow cascade in UE4

Tags: hlsl, unreal-engine4

I'm working on a blending effect for shadows that requires a world-space result of the depth differential between what is calculated for the source pixel vs what is encoded in the directional shadow cascade.

For instance, if I have 2 planes rendered into shadow buffer, one at a distance of 300 from the directional light, and another at a distance of 600 from the directional light. In the shadow cascade, these might be encoded as 0.3134 and 0.3155 or something like that.

I want to be able to take that remaining delta of 0.0021 and be able to convert that back to 300 in my shader.

Now, Unreal has a number of mechanisms available to (in theory) get this information back, like building InvDeviceZToWorldZTransform parameters you can build for any projection matrix.

I've gone through most of the matrices available in FProjectedShadowInfo for the directional light, yet nothing I've looked at would give me the correct parameters to do this conversion correctly.

Does anyone know what the right matrix to invert, or call CreateInvDeviceToWorldZTransform() on is?

Comment: I've solved (or at least solved with good enough results) by creating a scale from (MaxSubjectZ - MinSubjectZ)/InvMaxSubjectDepth and multiplying that to what is calculated for shadow pos or read in from texture.